# How to extract a sub-string between two characters?

Tags: python, list, search, substring

I want to extract all the dates inside `my_list`

```
my_list = ['FRE_5F_20200915-08u21m57s_ab', 'AY_C7_20200813-17u02m16s_ab', 'ALL_20200915-06u34m05s_ab', 'FF_20200816-11u21m44s_ab']
```

**This is my code:**

```
for file in my_list:
    find = re.search('_(.+?)-', file).group(1)
    print(find)
```

**This is the output:**

```
5F_20200915
C7_20200813
20200915
20200816
```

**This is my expected output:**

```
20200915
20200813
20200915
20200816
```

Comment: `_(.+?)-` the dot will match anything.   You just want digits.  Because the longest marched string is returned is why you get 5F_20200915.  The shortest match would be 20200915.

Comment: True, just found out yes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_(\d+)-` [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JHweC1/1):

```
import re


my_list = ['FRE_5F_20200915-08u21m57s_ab', 'AY_C7_20200813-17u02m16s_ab', 'ALL_20200915-06u34m05s_ab', 'FF_20200816-11u21m44s_ab']
r = re.compile(r'_(\d+)-')

for s in my_list:
    m = r.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
20200915
20200813
20200915
20200816
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work, can you tell me what you exactly did?

Comment: @NorthAfrican The `_(\d+)-` pattern will search for all digits (0-9) between characters `_` and `-`. See here https://regex101.com/r/JHweC1/1

Comment: Ah okay It works perfect however I think the answer of goldwave is a bit easier!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your regex, your output matches your regex. To only match numbers between `_` and `-` you can use `'_(\d+)-'` as seen below

```
import re
my_list = ['FRE_5F_20200915-08u21m57s_ab', 'AY_C7_20200813-17u02m16s_ab', 'ALL_20200915-06u34m05s_ab', 'FF_20200816-11u21m44s_ab']
for file in my_list:
    find = re.search('_(\d+)-', file).group(1)
    print(find)
```

Which results in

```
20200915
20200813
20200915
20200816
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without a regex:

```
for s in my_list:

    # find the index of -
    index = s.index("-")

    # extract 8 characters before that
    print(s[index-8:index])
```